# How to number theorems depending on whether there is a subsection

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, sections-paragraphs, ntheorem

I am trying to typeset a exam subject with the same numbering as [this document by Concours CentraleSupélec](http://www.concours-centrale-supelec.fr/CentraleSupelec/2016/MP/sujets/2014-032.pdf).

Sections are numbered with Roman, subsections are numbered with Alph and questions are numbered within each subsection with arabic : that is, question number 2 within subsection A of section I has number I.A.2.

I know how to do this with ntheorem and KOMA scrartcl : it suffices to do

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\Alph{subsection}}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}[subsection]
```

And this works.

However, not all sections have subsections. In this case, questions are numbered within the section and with Alph, not arabic. So the third question in a section IV that does not have subsections is numbered IV.C, not IV..3.

I know I can do

```
\theoremnumbering{Alph}
\renewtheorem{question}{Question}[section]
```

I am trying to automate this. Clearly, it is not possible, when encountering a new section, to know whether there will be a subsection or not, so one has to change the numbering at each section and again at each subsection (or at least each first subsection within a section).

I could not find a `AtBeginSection` or `AtBeginSubsection` in the KOMA-script manual. Is there some hook that I can use to execute some code at each section/subsection without hacking the whole thing ?

Comment: A complete minimal working example would have been nice. `\AtBeginSection` and `\AtBeginSubsection` are `beamer` commands, I don't know whether there is a package that does provide them to KOMA. Though one could use `etoolbox`'s `\pretocmd` (as I did) or `\apptocmd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does what you want. I just redefined `\thequestion` to check for the current `\value` of `subsection` (which is `\c@subsection`) and based on that print it differently.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{ntheorem}

\renewcommand*\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand*\thesubsection{\thesection.\Alph{subsection}}

\newtheorem{question}{Question}[subsection]
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\thequestion{%
  \ifnum\c@subsection=0
    \thesection.\Alph{question}%
  \else
    \thesubsection.\arabic{question}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\begin{question}
  foo
\end{question}

\section{Foo}
\subsection{Bar}
\begin{question}
  foo
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

**Issue:** What if you have something like the following structure:

```
I. Section
  A. Question
  B. Subsection
    1. Question
```

**Solution:** Add a Boolean switch to the `\section` and `\subsection` command which indicates whether we are inside a subsection and if so use `thesubsection.\arabic{question}`. If not step the subsection counter and use `\thesection.\Alph{question}`. For the patching part I used `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newif\ifInsideSubsection
\pretocmd\section{\InsideSubsectionfalse}{}{}
\pretocmd\subsection{\InsideSubsectiontrue}{}{}

\renewcommand*\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand*\thesubsection{\thesection.\Alph{subsection}}

\newtheorem{question}{Question}[subsection]
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\thequestion{%
  \ifInsideSubsection
    \thesubsection.\arabic{question}%
  \else
    \thesection.\Alph{question}%
    \global\advance\c@subsection by 1\relax
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\begin{question}
  foo
\end{question}

\section{Foo}
\begin{question}
  foo
\end{question}
\subsection{Bar}
\begin{question}
  foo
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There shouldn't be `\relax` in the definition of `\thequestion`; just don't put `%` after `0`. It's questionable to have `\advance` in `\thequestion` (second solution).

Comment: By the way, you can also say `\ifnum\value{subsection}=0`, instead of going a level down to `\c@subsection`.

Comment: @egreg the `\advance` is there to ensure consistent numbering (if that is not needed one can just use the first approach). `\stepcounter` didn't work there and I didn't want to dig to deep into it, so I just used `\advance`. My first code had  `\value{subsection}` instead of `\c@subsection` don't know why I changed that but I think there is no harm in doing so. The `\relax` I started to use based on someone else here on TeX.SX who advised that (neither know who it was nor where exactly) to keep it safe (if `%` is used). But you're right, it isn't needed. Does it any harm (serious question)?

Comment: Just a note to say sorry for accepting the answer after such a delay --- the CentraleSupélec template is indeed much more complicated than that and I finally opted to diverge from it, but the proposed answer does do what was intended in my first question.